# Export a question and its answers as LaTeX

Tags: app, website, posts

A post on a [MathJax-enabled SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) is typically a mix of LaTeX-like syntax and HTML and/or Markdown. Consequently, the source of a post cannot be processed by a LaTeX compiler as is, despite the syntax similarities. After someone [asked](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15230/) about a way to save a post in LaTeX format, I made the following rudimentary web app:

### [Save as LaTeX](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/savetex.html)

Paste in the URL of any question on a MathJax-enabled SE site to get the question and its answers as a single LaTeX document, which can be copy-pasted into a compiler such as TeXworks, MiKTeX or web-based [Overleaf](http://overleaf.com). The questions are  ordered by votes. Inclusion of comments is optional. It is also possible to get all of one's favorite questions at once.

#### Limitations

- The sites with \$ delimiters (currently EE and Code Review) are not supported.
- Some posts may throw errors at compilation, requiring additional manual corrections (typically minor).

Here is how [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312385/) looked after being processed:

[image: sample]